# Unity- how to stream videos from external source?

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, video

I'm working on a Unity level for a VR project that requires displaying multiple 360 videos in a hall. These videos are large (8k and 60 minutes each) so cannot be contained in the app itself. Is it possible to have them streamed from an external site (AWS, Vimeo)?

Comment: Can your target hardware display the 8k as well? Can you break down the video into smaller chunks and have maybe the first minute or so locally in your app while you stream load the rest if needed? One minute of 8k is close to 600MB, 36GB to load in real time is going to be hard in itself

Answer (score 0):

The [video player component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-VideoPlayer.html) is able to [load videos from the Internet](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Video.html). Just change "Source" from "Video Clip" to "URL" and enter the `https://` URL of the video file. There is also an article [specifically on how to use a 360° video on a skybox material](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VideoPanoramic.html) which might or might not fit your particular use-case.

Note that the URL must point to *the file*, not to a website embedding the file. So `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ` is not going to work. For that reason I would recommend to host the videos on a plain old webserver and not on a dedicated video hosting platform.

But you might not want to go with the cheapest option. A 360° video requires to stream 6 different videos simultaneously. And no, you can not just cull those in the direction the user isn't looking at right now, because you don't want them to look at a buffering-placeholder when they turn around. When each one of them has 8k resolution, then that's going to create quite a lot of traffic. Webhosting which is able and willing to provide that much bandwidth per user is going to be costly. (And no, [I can not give you any recommendation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/))